# How to use Isotope to filter a single random image with Javascript from an array

Tags: javascript, random, filtering, jquery-isotope, image-gallery

Using Isotope filtering. http://isotope.metafizzy.co.

How can I add filtering to show only 1 image chosen at random. Each time the menu button "RANDOM" is clicked a new selected random image would be shown.
I'm assuming I can some javascript to generate a random number which could correspond to the numbers in the image class (not added to the code yet), but need this to re-randomise each time the menu button is clicked.. Hope that's clear and there's enough info..

html

```
<ul id="filters">
<li class="filter"><a href="#" data-filter=".RANDOM" title="RANDOM">RANDOM</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="gallerycontainer">
    <div class="item RANDOM">
        <a href="$Link" title="$Title">
            <img src="image.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
<div>
```

isotope-init.js

```
$(window).load(function() {
var $container = $('#gallerycontainer');
// init
$container.isotope({
// options
itemSelector: '.item', 
layoutMode: 'masonry',
isOriginLeft: 'false'

});
// filter items on button click
$('#filters').on( 'click', 'a', function( event ) {
var filtr = $(this).attr('data-filter');
$container.isotope({ filter: filtr });
});
});
```

UPDATE:

I have this which I think will work: http://jsfiddle.net/sMu69/137/
But I'm not sure how to target the "data-filter" rather than the innerHTML?

```
<a href="#" class="button" id="message" value="Search" data-filter="*"   
onclick="GetValue();">click</a>

function GetValue()
{
var myarray= new Array("item1","item2","item3");
var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=random;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found this solution:

HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="GetValue();" id="myid" data-filter="">RANDOM</a>

<div id="gallerycontainer">
<div class="item Filter1">
    <a href="$Link" title="$Title">
        <img src="image.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="item Filter2">
    <a href="$Link" title="$Title">
        <img src="image.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="item Filter3">
    <a href="$Link" title="$Title">
        <img src="image.jpg">
    </a>
</div>    
<div>
```

Javascript

```
function GetValue()
{
var myarray= new Array(".Filter1",".Filter2",".Filter3");
var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
document.getElementById("myid").dataset.filter = random;
}
```

Just have a unique data-filter for each image and add these to the array.